# two like buttons are displaying (both if and else are executing)

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

I am building a simple question and answer site in which i am implementing a simple like button, so I made another model for like the answer.

But it is showing two like button when i like the post.

models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=900)

class Answer(models.Model):
    question_of = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=900)

class AnswerLike(models.Model):
    answer_of = models.ForeignKey(Answer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    liked_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py

```
def question_detail(request, question_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)

    answers = post.answer_set.all()

    context = {'post':post, 'answers':answers}
    return render(request, 'question_detail.html', context)


def answer_like(request, answer_id):
     answer = get_object_or_404(Answer, pk=answer_id)

     if request.GET.get('submit') == 'like':
        save_like = AnswerLike.objects.create(answer_of=answer, liked_by=request.user)

        return JsonResponse({'liked':'liked'})
```

question_detail.html

```
{{post}}

{% for ans in answers %}

{{ans.body}}

{% for likes in ans.answerlike_set.all %}


<form method="GET" class="AnswerLike" action="{% url 'answer_like' ans.id  %}">

    {% if request.user == likes.liked_by %}

    <button name='submit' type='submit' value="UnLike"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i>Liked</button>

    {% else %}

    <button name='submit' type='submit' value="Like"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i>
Not Liked</button>

    {% endif %}

  {% empty %}


    <button name='submit' type='submit' value="Like"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i>
Not Liked</button>

  {% endfor %}

</form>

{% endfor %}
```

I know that i am using `if statement` like **If user liked the post then show liked post liked icon** and in `else statement` **If request.user not liked the post then show blank like icon**

and `empty statement` if nobody liked the post then show `blank like button`

So i think :- It is executing both `if` and `else` statement, And I have no idea how can i use only one at a time.

Any help would be much Appreciated. Thank You in Advance